# Correct way of using a constant in the .module files object of the $ocLazyLoader

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

I am using $ocLazyLoader to load some .js files for the dropdown module. 
I would like to set a root path for the files property. The problem is that I do not seem to be able to inject my app.constant 'config' here. This is the code:

```
var root = "./templates/trainingtrips/app/";    
angular
    .module('dropdown', {
        files: [
            root + 'modules/directives/dropdown.js',
            root + 'modules/services/dropdownService.js'
        ]
    })
```

This is what I would like to do (this code doesn't work of course):

```
// remove the local var
    angular
        .module('dropdown', ['config', function(config) {
            files: [
                config.root + 'modules/directives/dropdown.js',
                config.root + 'modules/services/dropdownService.js'
            ]
        }])
```

What would be the correct way to use a constant in this module files object?

Update:
Constant file

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('teemr')
        .constant('config', {
            appName: 'Teemr',
            appVersion: 0.1,
            root: './templates/trainingtrips/teemr-app/'
        });

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `constant` method is for. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant

```
angular
    .module('dropdown', ['root', function(root) {
        files: [
            root + 'modules/directives/dropdown.js',
            root + 'modules/services/dropdownService.js'
        ]
    }])
    .constant('root', './templates/trainingtrips/app/');
```

This is untested and I may have missed something, because it's just off the top of my head.

---

Based upon the edited question and comments below, I think you want your module like this:

```
angular
    .module('dropdown', ['teemr.config', {
        config: teemr.config
    }]);
```

Comment: I'm declaring the constant in a separate file (modules/constants/config.js) under an other module name. It was my intension to create a constant app-wide. So I could access it in other modules.

Comment: Could you post an example of that module?

Comment: Added to original post :)

Comment: The second argument for the .module should be an object with files as a property. So your first solution does not work. It tried to let the function(config) to return the files object. That didn't work either. The second solution is not what I want. You are sharing the files constant. But I want to share the root constant. So I can use config.root in the second argument (the object with the files property).

Comment: Edited again, to just have a property called config which comes from the `teemr` module.